# Entity Framework Connection String issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm using EF Code First with MVC3.

If I don't specify a connection string in my web config the application works fine.
On start up it creates the database and tables and everything works fine.

If I specify a connection string for an new empty database I created it doesn't create the tables and I get an error when running the application. The error is essential a null pointer since the table doesn't exist and I'm trying to query it.

Here is my connection string:

```
 <add name="MyContextName" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

MyContextClass

```
    public class MyContextName : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> books{ get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Let me show your "Context" class please

Comment: Try to connect using MS Server Management Studio, to check if the connection string really works.

Comment: I added the database to Server Explorer in VS2010 and copied the connection string from the properties.

Comment: Well I manually created the tables in my database and everything works now, but it should create the tables for me. So I'm still missing something, but I'll figure it out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem to be with my process. I created a new empty database then copied the connection string to my web config. It seems you're not suppose to create the database at all. Just set the connection string and like EF generate the database for you.

Answer (score 2):

If this your connection string then you have a copy error in it,

you have written "Data Source=" twice,

see below

<add name="MyContextName" connectionString="`Data Source=`Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: The copy error was a mistake when edited here. Its not the actual problem I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

Replace :

```
<add name="MyContextName" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

By:

```
<add name="MyContextName" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|databasename" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: That was a mistake when I posted it here. Also I accidentally  edited your post thinking it was mine... Sorry.